# Server chat application

Tags: php, android, ios, livechat

I need for a project to build a live chat with:

- group chat room
- private chat (user-user);
- web site interface;
- mobile interface;
- others information (profile etc).

I want to start obviously from the server: any PHP framework or tutorial to do this ?
Otherwise, any full-solution (but customizable) with web site + mobile compatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XMPP Server (XMPP server uses Socket programming, so once a connection will be establish, then it uses that connection each and everytime, you no need to create connection everytime, like HTTP).

Or Use GCM (Using Push Notification you can send and receive messages as well).

Here are some [Source Code - Github](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android)

[Source from google](https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)

Hope it helps.

Comment: What difference from XMPP Server or the solution with GCM (or APNS for iOS) ?

Comment: Can I integrate this two ? Because I need  website solution too.

Comment: group chat is not possibel in  APNS for iOS  but website solutions is  also possible

Comment: APNS can be done by handling the notification using the delegate methods, and here is a full explanation  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: For Group chat use Comet with PHP.

or Robbiehanson's iOS XMPPFramework for iOS devices

Answer (score 1):

http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.pt/2011/01/writing-xmppjabber-chat-application-for.html

This would be the best place to start!

Have fun building the app!

Also if you really want to get deep into it, Xabber source code will prove of great help.

Answer (score 0):

XMPP is a communication protocol for message-oriented middleware based on XML (Extensible Markup Language). In plain words it is a protocol used for instant messaging. 
While APNS and GCM are services used to set up push notifications for your apps. 
So, it's a bit different.

I believe building a chat app from scratch is not an easy task for you.
So, I'd recommend using a ready backend and concentrate on client-side implementation of your app.

For backend you need to choose a provider with the set of features most suitable for your project and then start app development with the API provided by your backend provider. You might find this [article](https://connectycube.com/2018/09/12/product-comparison-connectycube-vs-sendbird-vs-applozic-vs-layer/) useful when choosing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking to get going fast on your chat implementation...the xmpp implementation is one way. Firebase provides another. Having implemented messaging via xmpp as well as firebase, I can offer up this tip: stable connectivity and auto-reconnect logic in an openfire+SMACK implementation is not particularly reliable. I have had recurring troubles maintaining connection in the face of drop offs; updates in Openfire that may or may not conform to the older SMACK library versions are not helpful (no one guarantees for conformity - you are on your own). Others with more xmpp-based experience may attest to these difficulties. Firebase is not without its own challenges but I found them manageable. I also recommend you checkout at least one opensource chat library implementation via firebase (github [link](https://github.com/DabKickDeveloper/DKLiveChat/tree/DKLiveChat-3.0) being one such). With firebase the connectivity issue largely goes away and a host of new options open up. I prefer if the backend is fully taken care of by the library provider so we only need to focus on UI. Hope this is helpful.